# print all items saved in a core data string1

Tags: swift, core-data, printing, fetch, nsfetchrequest

I want my swift code to print out the strings attributes. Right now when calling the function I am getting a runtime error at context. I just want to print out all of each string entry. I have added the function in question below.

**Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value**

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate //Singlton instance
var context:NSManagedObjectContext!

@objc func pressRight(){
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Place>(entityName: "Name")
      do {
          let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
          let nameArray = result.map{$0.name}
          print(nameArray)
      } catch {
         print("Could not fetch \(error) ")
      }

   
    
}
```

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UkXO.png)

Comment: The `context` is not initialized though I believe ?

Comment: You are calling a NSFetchRequest on Place but for entity “Name”, is that a mistake?

Comment: "I am getting a runtime error at context" What error?

Comment: @Larme I bolded what the error message is my question above.

Comment: @HunterLion I added a photo above if that helps.

Comment: With `var context:NSManagedObjectContext!`, you stated that you'll have a `context` value, and when you'll use it, it won't be nil (or prove me wrong by crashing with that error). So question: Why is it nil? Where did you do `context = someValue`?

Answer (score 0):

select manual in code gen
[image]
then create custom class of place add to your project
[image]
You are using the wrong entity name "Name" instead of "Place"

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class CoreDataManager {

    static let shared = CoreDataManager()
    private init() {}
    lazy var coreDataStack = CoreDataStack(modelName: "Place")

    func allNames() -> [String]? {
      let request: NSFetchRequest<Place> = Place.fetchRequest()
      do {
        // Peform Fetch Request
        let places = try coreDataStack.managedContext.fetch(request)
        return places.map({$0.name})
      } catch {
        print("Unable to Fetch Workouts, (\(error))")
      }
      return nil
  }

func allPlaces() -> [Place]? {
      let request: NSFetchRequest<Place> = Place.fetchRequest()
      do {
        // Peform Fetch Request
        let places = try coreDataStack.managedContext.fetch(request)
        return places
      } catch {
        print("Unable to Fetch Workouts, (\(error))")
      }
      return nil
  }
}
```

if you still getting error then before this initialize your context
managedObjectContext/context you force unwrapping it

add this stack class

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class CoreDataStack {

private let modelName: String
lazy var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    return self.storeContainer.viewContext
}()

init(modelName: String) {
    self.modelName = modelName
}

private lazy var storeContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: self.modelName)
    container.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    return container
}()

func saveContext() {
    guard managedContext.hasChanges else {return}
    do{
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

func updateContext() {
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

func clearChange() {
    managedContext.rollback()
}
```

}
then how to use it
in your view controller viewDidLoad() function or any other button tap action you can get your place names like this

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//       here you get all names 
           let names = CoreDataManager.shared.allNames()
           print(names)
           let places = CoreDataManager.shared.allPlaces()
           print(places)
           let namesAgain = places.map({$0.name})
           print(namesAgain)
     }
```

Comment: I am getting a error Cannot find 'coreDataStack' in scope

Comment: copy above two classes to your project